# ClassCastException in Android ScrollView

Tags: java, android, inheritance, multi-level

There is a class in my project (B) which extends (not directly)  ScrollView (A) which can be used to set a value in the month field scroll which is vertical

Here is the inheritance heirarchy:
B extends D which extends an abstract class E which extends A

I am using a robotium method which gets all the scroll views in the present activity which returns an ArrayList of scrollviews(ArrayList) .

I am trying to assign the first element of that arraylist ArrayList.get(0) and trying to cast it to the B object doing it as follows:

```
ScrollView scrview =  new ScrollView(a.getApplicationContext());
ChildScrollView scrview1 = new ChildScrollView(a.getApplicationContext());

scrview = solo.getScrollViews().get[0];
scrview1 = (ChildScrollView) scrview; // I get the classcastexception here
```

Is there any way to get around this?

I also tried

```
ChildScrollView scrview1 = new ChildScrollView(a.getApplicationContext());
ScrollView scrview =  (ScrollView)new childScrollView(a.getApplicationContext());
//Also tried this --> ScrollView scrview = (ScrollView) scrview1;

scrview = solo.getScrollViews().get[0];
scrview1 = (ChildScrollView) scrview; // I get the classcastexception here
```

Any help would be appreciated. Let me know if I am missing something.

Comment: Classes can be cast to ones from which they inherit, not the other way around

Answer (score 2):

You are getting an exception because the cast cannot work like that. Think about it this way: All `ChildScrollView` are also `ScrollView`, so it makes sense to use them in a `ScrollView` context. But a `ScrollView` object may or may not be a `ChildScrollView`.

You could use [reflection](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/ALT/Reflection/) to try to determine the object's class at runtime before casting to ensure that the cast is safe. However, I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish with your code above. You created a new object referred to by `scrview1`, but then immediately assign that variable to `scrview`? Can you give any more details about what you want to accomplish?

Comment: I am writing a script using robotium which will use a method from the Child class to click on a particular value in a scroll list which can scrolled up or down. However, I can get the scroll views only in a parent object. The child class then has a method setMonth(int pos) which will set the month to the pos in the parameter which is not present in the parent class. Also I tried seeing if (child instanceof parentclass) works and it returns true.

Comment: I ended up iterating through the different scroll views and fetching the appropriate views using a method which had a template parameter (class <? extends Scrollview>).